# Make maven build fail created artifact contains certain classes

Tags: maven, build, maven-ear-plugin

I have complex multi-pom setup that in the end will create an EAR package. Sometimes the dependencies are messed up and some unwanted dependencies like JUnit end up in the final EAR package.

Is there a way to make maven build fail if final artifact contains certain classes?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not failing but you can exclude some jar-files that you know you will never use.

The `maven-ear-plugin` has a tag to use when excluding files, look [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/examples/excluding-files-from-ear.html).

Use the `<packagingExcludes/>` tag to exclude JUnit for example.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-enforcer-plugin/) with a [custom rule](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) that you probably would have to write yourself. I haven't searched, but I don't think that such a rule exists yet.